# Подписка на приложения

Tags: android, google-play-console

Я выпустил приложение с платной подпиской на него на протяжении **нескольких месяцев подписка в тех кто на нее подписывался работала** без проблем было 2 активных подписки не более. Вот когда приложение стало более популярным и пользователь взял 3 подписку она в него не сработала и он написал это мне в отзыв. **Я протестировал данную версию приложение и версию в которой была рабочая подписка в итоге ни в одной версии приложения на данный момент подписка не работает.**

Подскажите может что то за этих 2 месяца изменилось по поводу подписок?

Comment: Если вы ничего не трогали и перестала работать прежде работавшая подписка то, возможно, дело на стороне гугла. Лично я заметил в своём приложении подобную проблему - переодически у юзеров это не работает. К тому же валидация подписок на сервере работает только в 50% случаев - это статистика самого гугла в моём случае. Коли всё вышеизложенное верно - то вы ничего сделать не можете и, возможно, оно всё заработает позже само. Возможно, также, стоит в техподдержку гугла написать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но как обратится в тех поддержку Google в какую именно их ведь полно. От Console, Adsense, или Google Play?

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте первую - кажется оно более подходит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через несколько дней после блокировки ( я не успел написать в поддержку Google) Google прислал вот такое мне письмо:

> Iambulance: Check out the latest subscriptions updates from Playtime
>   2018, and more tips on how to optimize your subscription app.  What’s
>   new on subscriptions
>
> • Tools for retaining subscribers: after introducing the cancellation
>   survey we're now testing the ability for users to temporarily pause
>   their subscriptions instead of outright canceling, and giving you the
>   ability to deliver promotions to win back canceled subscribers.
>
> • Execute a mandatory price change: you can now execute a mandatory
>   price change on an existing subscription without needing to create a
>   new SKU.
>
> • More flexibility in subscription upgrades and downgrades: you can
>   now offer a plan change and make the change effective at the existing
>   renewal date rather than on the date of change. • Automatically
>   enabling subscription restore for all apps: by the end of Q1 2019 we
>   will automatically enable subscription restore for all apps with the
>   ability to opt out.
>
> • Recognize when multiple purchase tokens belong to the same
>   subscription by using linkedPurchaseToken: check out our Medium post
>   to ensure correct users have access to your content.   Early Access
>   Programs  Express interest for these early access subscription
>   features:
>
> • Pause subscriptions: allows the user to pause their subscription for
>   up to 3 months. In preliminary testing we've seen positive impacts on
>   churn & subscription resurrection.
>
> • Subscription retention promotion: allows you to serve up a
>   promotional offer when a user is trying to cancel.
>
> • Subscribe & install (US Only): allows you to promote your free trial
>   offer in the Store with a better user flow to improve sign up rates.
>   The flow is designed to save steps for the user, they will now be able
>   to subscribe & install at the same time.

и возобновил подписку на моё приложение. 
Так что не впадайте в панику если у Вас будет такая проблема бывают ещё ошибки со стороны Google.