# Задержка активации inapp purchases в приложении с GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play

За последнюю неделю уже несколько раз столкнулся с тем, пользователь оплачивает покупку в приложении, но активации дополнительного контента не происходит.

Стал разбираться, оказывается, иногда Гугл даёт на активацию до 24 часов. Непонятно из каких соображений.

С другой стороны - многие покупки по-прежнему совершаются мгновенно. Использую стандартную (предлагаемую Гуглом) систему inapp, которая была год назад, код типовой.

**Собственно, вопрос:** кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой (последнее время)? Возможно необходимо внести какие-то изменения в код inapp.

Нашел в Google какой-то [новый способ](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) `billing`'a. Является ли он типовым, обязательным и делающим невозможным работу предыдущих версий?

Comment: Вы не одиноки. Вот ещё человек с проблемой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918625/17609 Там же и я отписался о похожих проблемах. Судя по всему это какие-то проблемы на стороне гугла и надо просто надеяться на то, что оно всё само починится на их стороне их стараниями. Новый способ ничем не поможет - он внутри использует старый способ, никаких отличий нет.

Comment: да, читал этот вопрос с вашими комментариями. Значит здесь то же самое. Спасибо, понял!

Comment: Коллега. вы в курсе, что в описаниях меток не допускается копипаста и есть [специальная причина для отклонения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/335979)? Можете пояснить как-то причину по которой вы решили принять данную правку?

Comment: 1. Нет, был не в курсе; 2. Потому что 1.